# Upper-bounding $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\tilde{p}}{p} a \right]$ with $D(p, \tilde{p})+ \mathbb{E}[a]$?

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation

Define two slightly different probability distributions: 
$$
p_k = \frac{ \exp \left[ - \eta L_k \right] }{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^K \exp \left[ - \eta L_{i} \right] }, \quad \tilde{p}_k = \frac{ \exp \left[ - \eta ( L_k  + \ell_k ) \right] }{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^K \exp \left[ - \eta (L_{i} + \ell_{i} )\right] } 
$$
in which $L_k$ and $\ell_k$ are chosen randomly from some unknown distribution.
Each of the probabilities $p$ and $\tilde{p}$ is defined over $K$ actions (e.g. $K = 2$ in Binomial case). 
Define a shorthand notation: 
$$
p = (p_1, p_2, p_3, ..., p_K)
$$
Similarly define $\tilde{p}$ which is a slightly modified version of $p$.

Suppose we sample $a$ according to $p$: 
$$
\mathbb{P}(a=k) = p_k
$$

> Any ideas if we can find a non-trivial upperbound on $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\tilde{p}_k}{p_k} a \right]$ which is of the form $D(p, \tilde{p})+ \mathbb{E}[a]$, where $D(p, \tilde{p})$ is a divergence measure (that we get to choose) between $p$ and $\tilde{p}$?

Trivially when $p = \tilde{p}$ then $D(p, \tilde{p}) = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\tilde{p}_k}{p_k} a \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[  a \right]$.

Comment: Several things need to be clarified: Is $A$ a discrete random variables with support $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\}$ such that $\Pr\{A = a_i|(P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k)\} = P_i$? Those $L_i$ i.i.d. random variables? and are independent of $l$? What is $P$ (and $\tilde{P}$)? If it is a vector, then what is the fraction $\frac {\tilde{P}} {P}$ inside the expectation?

Comment: @BGM thanks for the feedback. Fixed the issues you pointed out. See if it reads better now?

Comment: It seems that $p_k=\tilde p_k$ for every $k$.

Comment: @Did is it? Their definitions are similar, but different. (Unless I have made a mistake somewhere)

Comment: Factoring $e^{-\eta l}$ in the numerator and denominator of $\tilde p_k$ and simplifying them seems to show that indeed $\tilde p_k=p_k$.

Comment: @Did my bad again. Was missing an index from `l_k`. Fixed it. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Now, $p\ne\tilde p$ in general.